# How can I number rows automatically, repeating the numbers based on two columns/criteria in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This formula starts counting based on a column. I'd like to learn however how can I have it repeat the numbers for client A, even though there is more than one row with their name?
`={"Task No.";ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(C2:C), SORT(ROW(C2:C),SORT(ROW(C2:C),C2:C,1),1)-MATCH(C2:C,SORT(C2:C),0),))}`

| CLient | Status | Task No |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Planned | 1 |
| A | Cancel | 1 |
| B | Planned | 2 |
| A | Done | 1 |
| C | Planned | 3 |
| C | Done | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(u,UNIQUE(A2:A),{"Task No";XLOOKUP(A2:A,u,SEQUENCE(ROWS(u)),)}))
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks! If it so happens that instead of A, I want to use a couple more columns to build unique keys, will it work by wrapping the columns in a `{}` or this deserves another question?